# Is the distribution of a random variable normal if it is conditionally normal and the conditioning variable is normal?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, gaussian

Suppose we have a variable $\xi\sim N(\mu_2,\sigma_2)$ and another conditional variable $\eta | \xi \sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_1)$. Is $\eta$ normally distributed, and if so what is its mean and variance?

I think this has something to do with Bayes rule and the fact that the conditionals and marginals of multivariate normals are all normals, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: Do you mean $\eta|\xi \sim N(\xi, \sigma_1)$?

Comment: No, $\mu_1(\xi)$ is a function of the other variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the characteristic function of $\eta$ is
\begin{align*}
\varphi_\eta(t) &= \mathbb{E}e^{it\eta} \\
&= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[e^{it\eta}|\xi]] \\
&= e^{-\sigma_1^2t^2/2}\mathbb{E}[e^{it\mu_2(\xi)}]
\end{align*}
If $\mu_2(\xi) = a + b\xi$, then the result is the characteristic function for $N(a + b\mu_1, \sigma_1^2 + b^2\sigma_2^2)$. Otherwise, for example $\mu_2(\xi) = \xi^2$, then $\eta$ is something that is pretty chaotic; for general $\mu_2(\xi)$, $\eta$ is not always normal.

Comment: But here $\sigma_1(\xi)$ also depends on the random variable so you cannot take it out of the expectation

Comment: Even in the simpler case where $\sigma_1(\xi)$ is fixed, we don't necessarily have normality. Allowing $\sigma_1(\xi)$ to depend on $\xi$ will only add more complexity to make it non-normal.